# What if AIX dynamic library imports one of symbols from wrong place

Tags: unix, aix, library, binary, ppc

I have a legacy AIX ppc64 library `mylib.so`.

Inspecting `dump -Tv` output, I noticed it expects that `Foo` symbol would be present in even older library `oldfoo.so`. However, it seems after new foo release, they moved `Foo` symbol to other soname: `foocommon.so` and `oldfoo.so` is no longer exports it, but rather just imports from `foocommon.so`.

And `mylib.so` is thus broken, dynamic linker refuses to work with binary linked with `mylib.so`, saying that `Foo` is not exported from `oldfoo.so`.

It isn't indeed, it is now resides in `foocommon.so`. Can I somehow edit binary `mylib.so`, changing name of actual location of `Foo` symbol or otherwise tell dynamic linker where to look?

I have tried setting environment variables:

```
export LDR_PRELOAD=foocommon.so
export LDR_PRELOAD64=foocommon.so
```

hoping that regular Linux approach would work, but that didn't changed the error produced by linker, still refusing to run my executable, as `Foo` symbols is not exported by `oldfoo.so`.

This is especialy obscure, since it is not clear of anyone still has `mylib.so` sources to re-comple and re-link it properly.

Comment: What version of AIX is this? From 6.1 onwards LDR_PRELOAD won't work unless you disable RBAC first..

Comment: It is exactly 6.1 thanks for the pointer to RBAC. Not sure if would help, but i'll try reading on it.

Comment: It won't work, unless you relink `mylib.so`. Hope you don't mind, I used your question as an example in a FAQ-entry: http://web.axelero.hu/lzsiga/aix-linking.html#Q0038

Comment: Wow, thats nice! Consider making an answer with excerpt and link to your FAQ, it actually solves my problem, would be nice if i could accept it in your favor. One addition though: at least on 64bit aix, you have to pass `-d64` for `ld` as well, otherwise it'll refuse to extract object file and link it back in, complaining about function unavailability in 32-bit mode. Also don't forget to post full copy of awk script converting symbols description from `dump` format to `ld` one, just in case link will perish sooner than serverfault will, and script is really short.